# Query Android dictionary always empty

Tags: android

I've been trying to check if a word exists in the dictionary but I always get "false" as a response. Now I tried passing as the selection criteria, which means I should get all rows in the dictionary, but I still get "false" while executing "moveToFirst()". Any suggestions?

```
Cursor cursor = this.mainMenuActivity.getContentResolver().query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ UserDictionary.Words.WORD }, null, null, null);
boolean matched = cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: Are you testing this on a real device or an emulator? Are there words in the user dictionary? The query itself doesn't fail (or else `cursor` would be `null`).

Comment: I tried the code above in both and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I understood differently the purpose of the UserDictionary.Words contentprovider. After checking [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html) I noticed the provider is meant for **user entered words** and not just all words available in the dictionary.